# Marker not visible in Google Map Android v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hello I need help adding marker to the google map to show my current location. Even after using the addMarker() method and checking the API key, the marker is still not visible. I am able to get latitude, longitude values but the marker is not visible. I am trying to do it for fragment.

Here is my complete code:

```
public class WhereAmI extends Fragment {

GoogleMap googleMap;
TextView tv;
Location current;
LocationManager lm;
LocationListener locLis;
public static double lat=0.0000;
public static double longi=0.0000;
public static String addressString="Address Not Available";
LatLng Locateme;
public static String disp;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.whereami, container,false);
    tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lm=(LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);      
     locLis=new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            switch (arg1) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "AVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OUT_OF_SERVICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), provider+" Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), provider+" Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
                addressString="";
                lat=loc.getLatitude();
                longi=loc.getLongitude();
                Geocoder gc=new Geocoder(getActivity());
                List<Address> address;
                try{
                    address=gc.getFromLocation(lat, longi, 1);
                    for(int i=0;i<address.size();i++)
                    {   Address a=address.get(i);
                    for(int j=0;j<a.getMaxAddressLineIndex();j++){
                        addressString+=a.getAddressLine(j)+"\n";
                    }}

                    disp="Latitude: "+lat+"\n"+"Longitude: "+longi+"\n"+"Address: "+addressString;
                    tv.setText(disp);
                    if (googleMap == null) {
                       googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                       findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                       googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(lat,longi)).title("Current Location"));
                    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(lat, longi)).zoom(12).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }};         
    return v;
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 5, locLis);
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    lm.removeUpdates(locLis);
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried zooming out map manually, may be you would find marker somewhere?

Comment: you have big fat try-catch block around your entire logic. Is there any chance it crashes? Add log to your `catch` statement (or simply debug it) to double check this

Comment: @Aakash I tried zooming it manually, the whole map is visible. Just the marker is not there.

Comment: @PavelDudka I tried every possibility, it doesn't crash and the big fat try-catch block is to avoid AddressNotFound Exception or any other exception .

Comment: Is onLocationChanged being called?  Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: No I didn't debug the code but the geocder code inside onLocationChanged is being called since latitude longitude and address strings are getting displayed in the text view. Settext is before marker, and the text view is showing the location

Answer (score 0):

because you are sending `NULL` to the parameters i.e Latitude and Longitude.
Make sure you are getting the coordinates to pointer to point.